# CodeIgniter, including code from one view into another?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, scope

I have an interesting problem.  I currently have a basic template library that renders out a bunch of modules for header and footer templates, then sandwiches a view I specify in between them.
Example:

```
$this->load->view('header.php', $headerstuff);
$this->load->view($contentView);
$this->load->view('footer.php', $footerstuff);
```

The problem is that I need to put some javascript (that is specific to each content view) into the header.  I have been doing this with a switch statement containing the js inside the template library.  But that makes no sense in the mvc model.

Example (of what I've been doing), (in template library, above previous code):

```
$headerstuff['js'] = '';
switch ($contentView)
{
    case 'main':
        $headerstuff['js'] = 'JAVASCRIPT INCLUDE CODE 1';
        break;
    case 'product':
        $headerstuff['js'] = 'JAVASCRIPT INCLUDE CODE 2';
        break;
}
```

I can't think of another way to do this though.  I would like to (ideally) store the js in a variable inside the content view file, and (somehow) load that into the header view.  To be honest though, I don't even think that is possible.

Does anybody have a better way of doing this then my current solution?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Why not try and load the JavaScript into a variable in the controller? Then you could just check for the JS in the header view instead of using a switch in the template library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a helper file to do this for my sites and I think we have a similar MVC template layout:

Asset Helper:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('css'))
{
    function css($array) {
        // If the object passed is a string, convert it into an array
        if ( is_string($array) ) {
            $array = explode(" ", $array);
        }

        // Add additional CSS Files
        if ( isset($array) ) {
            foreach ( $array as $i => $file ) {
                // If it's not the first one add a tab character.
                if ( $i > 0 ) echo "\t";
                echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"". $file ."\">\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('js'))
{
    function js($array) {
        // If the object passed is a string, convert it into an array
        if ( is_string($array) ) {
            $array = explode(" ", $array);
        }

        // Add additional JavaScript Files
        if ( isset($array) ) {
            foreach ( $array as $i => $file ) {
                // If it's not the first one add a tab character.
                if ( $i > 0 ) echo "\t";
                echo "<script src=\"". $file ."\"></script>\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does one of two things. I will allow you to add files in the controller file which is nice. I do this by creating a data object:

```
$data['css'] = array('/path/to/styles.css', '/path/to/otherstuff.css');
$data['js'] = array('/path/to/javascript.js');
```

Then in your header include do the following:

```
<?
    $defaultCSS = array("/assets/css/global.css");
    $css = (isset($css)) ? array_merge($defaultCSS, $css) : $defaultCSS;        
    css($css);

    $defaultJS = array("/assets/js/global.js");
    $js = (isset($js)) ? array_merge($defaultJS, $js) : $defaultJS;
    js($js);
?>
```

I'm settings some defaults that will load on each page and then I can add in different files based on which controller I'm loading.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A good idea, I was hoping to have it per view (not controller) though, I use the same view over different controllers.  But I bet I could merge this with say a config file

Comment: The nice thing about this is it removes more logic out of your view. You ultimately have the same control but with this method you can quickly and easily use this on other projects.

Comment: A very good point (and a problem I just ran into), thanks for the helper class.  It will come in handy (I just wanted to make sure I could modify it to use a config file before I marked your answer).

Answer (score 0):

How about having a scripts controller which acts as a small proxy:

```
/**
 * A basic controller which allows for the display of basic views.
 */
class Scripts extends CI_Controller
{

    public function _remap( $meth, array $params )
    {
        // ensure that parent directory contents can't be revealed.
        if( !$meth || strpos( $meth, '.' ) !== FALSE ) show_404();
        foreach( $params as $arg )
            // I put all css in a folder called css all js goes into 
            // a folder called js. It can be overly simple, but it works

            // (if you need these files to be php files, just add '.php'
            // to the end of the FILE's name. No need to worry about that
            // here, CodeIgniter's got your back...)
            $this->load->view( "$meth/${params}.$meth" ); 
    }
}
```

How to use:

For each controller (or, you could easily modify this to be for every method), have an appropriate js file in your views/js folder. Name each after the respective controller. Then, point to each of them from the view:

Then, in the header view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="
<?php 

// honestly, I normally use a helper function here, but this is the 
// short... short version.
echo base_url() . '/scripts/js/' . load_class('Router')->fetch_class();
// You can also replace the controller name with the view name by using the
// variable $_ci_view, you can get the full path with $_ci_path

?>" ></script>
```

Best part? Your controller is agnostic about the contents of the view. The view is more or less agnostic of the controller (it is a variable populated ahead of time from an external source and just... there). In fact, the only things which "need to know" are the JS/CSS files and they were on a case by case configuration anyway.